# How to increase the transmission speed of data over the network when using Files.copy function to save the data?

Tags: java, file, sockets, kotlin, stream

I have a client application that sends a file to a server application and the other way around. The transmission speed is really slow (100KB/s) and I'm trying to identify the problem.
My connection speed is around 100Mbps down/12Mbps up and transferring files to the server through other applications have way higher throughput.

Below is the class on the server app that basically reads the data and saves it on the disk:

```
class AcceptFileResponseCreator: HttpResponseCreator {

    private val response = JSONObject()

    override fun computeResponse(httpExchange: HttpExchange): Triple<BufferedInputStream, Int, HashMap<String, String>> {

        try {

            logger.debug("Start accepting the request of uploading a file to the server...")

            val fileSize = httpExchange.requestHeaders.getFirst("Content-length").toLong()
            val md5OfTransferredFile = httpExchange.requestHeaders.getFirst(JSONFieldNames.API_HEADER_MD5)!!
            val targetId = httpExchange.requestHeaders.getFirst(JSONFieldNames.API_HEADER_TARGET_ID)!!
            val clientId = httpExchange.requestHeaders.getFirst(JSONFieldNames.API_HEADER_CLIENT_ID)!!
            val clientAuthentication = httpExchange.requestHeaders.getFirst(JSONFieldNames.API_HEADER_CLIENT_PASS)!!
            val fileName = decodeHTTPHeader(httpExchange.requestHeaders.getFirst(JSONFieldNames.API_HEADER_CLIENT_FILENAME)!!)
            val fileRelativePath = decodeHTTPHeader(httpExchange.requestHeaders.getFirst(JSONFieldNames.API_HEADER_CLIENT_RELATIVE_PATH)!!)
            val fileHash = httpExchange.requestHeaders.getFirst(JSONFieldNames.API_HEADER_CLIENT_FILE_HASH)!!


            val file = Manager.getEmptyFile()


            if (!file.parentFile.exists()) {
                file.parentFile.mkdirs()
            }
            logger.debug("Start saving the file on the server...")
            val amountOfBytesWritten = Files.copy(httpExchange.requestBody, file.toPath())
            Manager.addFileAsFileTransfer(fileName, fileRelativePath, fileHash, targetId, clientId, file)
            logger.debug("Wrote the file on the server at: ${file.absolutePath}")
            if (amountOfBytesWritten == fileSize) {
                return if (md5OfTransferredFile == file.md5()) {
                    logger.debug("File must have been written successfully! ($fileRelativePath/$fileName from client $clientId for $targetId)")
                    response.put(JSONFieldNames.REQUEST_ACCEPT, true)
                    Triple(response.toString().toByteArray().inputStream().buffered(), HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, HashMap())
                } else {
                    logger.debug("File md5 hash does not match! ($fileRelativePath/$fileName from client $clientId for $targetId)")
                    constructErrorResponse("File md5 hash uploaded on the server does not match!")
                    Triple(response.toString().toByteArray().inputStream().buffered(), HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR, HashMap())
                }
            }
            else {
                logger.debug("Amount of bytes written to the disk differ from the amount of the sender's data")
                constructErrorResponse("Amount of data received by the server is not correct.")
                return Triple(response.toString().toByteArray().inputStream().buffered(), HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR, HashMap())
            }

        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            Manager.logger.debug("Couldn't parse as JSON", e)
            constructErrorResponse("Request could not be parsed as a JSON object.", e.toString()).toString()
            return Triple(response.toString().toByteArray().inputStream().buffered(), HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND, HashMap())
        }

    }

    private fun constructErrorResponse(errorMessage: String = "Generic error", exceptionMessage:String = "") : JSONObject {
        response.put(HttpJSONFieldIdentifiers.REQUEST_ACCEPT, false)
        response.put(HttpJSONFieldIdentifiers.RESPONSE_ERROR, errorMessage)
        return response
    }

}
```

The method on the client app that sends the data is:

```
    /**
     * Sends a request to the server with the content of the data InputStream, at the specified uri. You can specify the request method and add any headers on the request by using the respective parameters.
     * @param data The data input stream that will be sent to the server
     * @param uri The URI that the request will be sent to
     * @param requestMethod The type of the HTTP request
     * @param headers The headers of the request
     */
    fun sendRequestSynchronous(data: InputStream, uri: String = "/", requestMethod: String = "POST", headers: Map<String, String> = HashMap()) : Triple<Int, MutableMap<String, MutableList<String>>, InputStream> {
        val path = "https://$serverHostname:$serverPort$uri"
        val connection = if (path.startsWith("https://")) (URL(path).openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection) else URL(path).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection


        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier { hostname, _ -> hostname == serverHostname }
        if (connection is HttpsURLConnection) {
            connection.sslSocketFactory = this.sslFactory
            connection.hostnameVerifier = CustomHostnameVerifier(serverHostname)
        }
        connection.doInput = true
        connection.doOutput = true
        connection.requestMethod = requestMethod
        headers.forEach {
            connection.addRequestProperty(it.key, it.value)
        }

        val totalAmountBytesToSend = data.available() // amount of bytes of the whole request
        var bytesSent = 0
        var bytesAmountToSent: Int // amount of bytes that will be sent in only one write call
        var amountOfBytesReadFromInput: Int
        while (bytesSent < totalAmountBytesToSend) {
            bytesAmountToSent = totalAmountBytesToSend - bytesSent
            if (bytesAmountToSent > ramUsagePerAction)
                bytesAmountToSent = ramUsagePerAction
            val bytes = ByteArray(bytesAmountToSent)
            amountOfBytesReadFromInput = data.read(bytes)
            if (amountOfBytesReadFromInput != bytesAmountToSent) {
                logger.error("Different amount of bytes read from input stream than expected! Read: $amountOfBytesReadFromInput, expected: $bytesAmountToSent")
            }
            connection.outputStream.write(bytes)
            bytesSent += bytesAmountToSent
        }

        connection.outputStream.flush()

        val code = connection.responseCode

        return Triple(code, connection.headerFields, connection.inputStream)
    }
```

Is there anything that I can improve? 
If you have a change that doesn't involve Files.copy on the server-app, that is also more than welcome if it speeds up things.

Comment: Despite the fact that the transmission speed with the above code is slow on that specific server compared to other applications (e.g. transferring a file through SSH using Mobaxterm), apparently the server has also quite limited download speed (1,2 MB/s was the maximum I could achieve while testing to download files on to the server from different services). I tested the code on a different server (which has 50MB/s connection) and it is much faster, so maybe it was just a network issue afterall and not a coding issue. If you have an idea though to improve the code, do tell.